# Testing if user created in AD can be logged into on a VM

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, azure-active-directory, automated-tests, rpa

I am a QA automation engineer and in the web app I test there's a feature that creates Active Directory users.
My tools are - Selenium (Java), RemoteWebDriver, Selenium Grid (Docker)

I was trying to find ways to validate this process and came to a stop - this field (AD) is new
to me and I need to find a way to make sure the user was created and can be logged into in the
network.
I was trying to find a way to do this and came up with 2 options, where the first one is the least
preferred way:

1. Make a request (API? 3rd side tool?) to get the relevant user(s).

- The issue:
  A user created and registered in the AD doesn't necessarily mean that the client can log into it (at least by the way I understood how AD works), and so it loses the most important consequence of the feature.

2. Use a VM, get the AD user information (username + password: possible) and try to log into the VM using those details.

- The issue:
  I haven't came across a tool that does it, the closest thing is Robot class or WinAppDriver.
  WinAppDriver seems like the best solution as of now although I don't know how to make the login process work since it's the process starts before the desktop is open and I don't know how to locate the username and password field, so I figured using Robot class seems like the simplest solution, if it works on a VM that is, which as of now doesn't seem like it does.

So, before advancing on learning how to use WinAppDriver with my current automation, I'd like and appreciate your opinions about the matter or if you have simpler solutions.
Thank you very much for reading!

Comment: Sound like the user needs to be a member of the domain?  For NTLM and website you might try putting credentials in the URL: https : // username:password@your_test_site.com"  The user would still need to be logged in to the domain though.  (which seems like it would be outside the scope of any automation... )

Comment: You should still be able to switch to different users (you may need to clear credentials)... it's just to begin with you'll need the account running the automation to be logged into domain.

Comment: Assuming you're automating AD on a test server here... one thing you might try is to timeout the credentials for the user who is running the test automation right before you add a new one.  It can then take another user's username/pw.  (no idea if it'll work in your setup for AD there... but seems like it would work the way we're setup here)

Comment: I did hear about putting credentials through the URL, but does it necessarily mean that the user is in the AD and can be logged into? (Not to the web server, but to Windows in general)

Answer (score 1):

•   We can check whether a user is created successfully or not and if that user can log in to the AD domain or not by executing a script as below. It is a powershell script that auto logs in through remote desktop protocol in the other domain joined VM from an Azure domain joined VM that checks whether the recently created user can login or not.

**Powershell script** : -

```
  cmdkey /list | ForEach-Object{if($_ -like "*target=TERMSRV/*"){cmdkey /del:($_ -replace " ","" -replace "Target:","")}}
  echo "Connecting to 192.168.1.100"
  $Server="192.168.1.100"
  $User="Administrator"
  $Password="AdminPassword"
  cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/$Server /user:$User /pass:$Password
  mstsc /v:$Server
```

•   In the above script, replace the **‘$user’** value by the user principal name of the newly created user, i.e., **‘$User=”testdemo@example.com”’** and the **‘$Password’** value by the password set for that user. Also, ensure that you replace and enter the correct IP address of the domain controller/AD server. Also, ensure that before executing the above powershell script, execute the below commands in an **elevated (administrator privileges)** powershell console.

```
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Lastly, please ensure that while creating the user, the option ***‘User must change password at next logon’, ‘Account is Disabled’, ‘Password never expires’ and ‘User cannot change password’*** are unchecked and not selected.

•   Also, you can use the below command line script for logging in to the domain joined Azure VM through RDP protocol. In the below command, replace the **‘username’** and **‘password’** with the username and password of the user created recently to log in to the Azure VM with this command line script. Also, replace the **‘TERMSRC’** with the hostname of the server system or the domain joined VM where the specified UNC path is located and replace the **‘some_unc_path’** with the actual path UNC path of the shared directory folder. Please execute the below command through elevated (administrator privileges) command prompt.

Command script: -

```
  c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nolog -command cmdkey /generic:TERMSRC/some_unc_path /user:username /pass:pa$$word; mstsc /v:some_unc_path
```